# Add value to the last empty cell in a defined column

Tags: vba, excel, copy

My model takes two numbers from one sheet, adds the average to another sheet in the last cell of a defined column. The problem that I have is that when I insert a new column, the references get missed up and I'm trying to have a macro that would 1. take the average 2. look for a specific column on the second sheet 3. paste the averaged value to the last cell.

Please help me with this I have been trying to get my head around it for a long time.

Thank you.

This is my code: what it basically does now is find the last emptyrow and I have to put in a number for a column to reference a cell. What I want is to have the column reference dynamic so when I insert a new column i dont have to change the macro.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim emptyRow As Long, Answer As Double, result As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheet1.Activate
    RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        .Offset(1, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
        .Offset(1, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
        .Offset(2, 2).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
        .Offset(2, 3).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
        .Offset(3, 2).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
        .Offset(3, 3).Value = Me.TextBox6.Value
        .Offset(4, 2).Value = Me.TextBox7.Value
        .Offset(4, 3).Value = Me.TextBox8.Value
    End With

    Sheet2.Activate

    emptyRow = Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
   Answer = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("C2:D2"))
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = Answer

    Answer = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("C3:D3"))
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = Answer

    Answer = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("C4:D4"))
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Answer

    Answer = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("C5:D5"))
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = Answer
End Sub
```

Comment: ...and what have you done so far? Please share your research with us.

Comment: I just added my code - thanks for the help  @lowak

Comment: What is your problem exactly ?

Comment: my problem is that I have to insert new columns and I need to keep the references dynamic when adding a value to the last empty cell in a column. For example: if i have salary as col A, and expenses as Col B - in this model that I have now I put in .Cells(emptyRow, 1) and .Cells(emptyRow, 2) now if I insert a column between A and B the references 1 and 2 will not work. Is there anyway that I can work around this where if i add a new column it wont mess up the references in the macro? Thanks @iDevlop

Answer (score 0):

One way is to assign a **Name** to the column:

```
Sub demo()
    Range("B:B").Cells.Name = "expenses"
End Sub
```

If columns are inserted at the beginning of the worksheet, the named range will adjust.

**EDIT#1:**

After the **Name** has been assigned, here is an example of filling the first empty cell *(at the bottom of the column)* of the *expense* column with the value **123**

```
Sub TheNextStep()
    Dim expCol As Long, FirstEmptyRow As Long
    expCol = Range("expenses").Column
    FirstEmptyRow = Cells(Rows.Count, expCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Cells(FirstEmptyRow, expCol).Value = 123
End Sub
```

Comment: So it would look like something like this?
 emptyRow = Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
   Answer = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("C2:D2"))
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(emptyRow, "expenses").Value = Answer

Comment: I tested what you wrote but it still posting values on column B when I insert a column before "expenses". Any idea why this is happening?